# How to send asynchronous call to application insights (AZURE)

Tags: azure, asynchronous, azure-application-insights

We have set up application insights (Azure) and the script is added to the project. I have noticed that sometimes this request is overlapping with the page's ajax request.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by " this request is overlapping with the page's ajax request"

Comment: @IvanYang calling request is waiting until the track function to complete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have confirmed with app insights team, actually the data(track or others) is sent to application insights backend async.

Here is his [feedback](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Home/issues/311):

```
The actual process of sending telemetry items to backend is done async. 'TrackXXX" 
calls result in items being stored in-memory and are sent async, in batches.
```

Hope it helps.